# How to get the list count using selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE to create my tests,I am testing a ticketing system ,in one of my case i want the total count of the new listed tickets,i tried commands like "storeAllLinks" ,"storeAllFields" but i didnt get the count i needed .is there any way to get the count,please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The `storeAllLinks` and `storeAllFields` return arrays.  You can use `storeEval` to run a .length with JavaScript on the array to count the number of items.  Use the stored value as you wish, in this case I just write it out to the IDE console.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAllLinks</td>
    <td>aLinks</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['aLinks'].length</td>
    <td>numberOfLinks</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${numberOfLinks}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ,its not the total links count i needed but i need the list count, i solved that issue what i did is i have take the xpath count.                                                             command:storeXpathCount                                              target://td[5]                                                       value:count                                                          command:echo                                              target:count                                                         //td[5]--it is the xpath of the position